# How to document automatically generated .designer.cs files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, doxygen

I have a project that contains many strongly typed DataSets.

I need to add some XML comment to them, but just a minor changes in the graphical DataSet editor causes the regeneration of the attached .designer.cs file wiping away any previously edited comment.

Besides the automatically generated code comments have a poor formatting:

```
/// <summary>
///After opening tag...
///The text is attached to the slashes, 
///causing doxygen to put the enclosing tag into doc
///</summary>
```

Since all automatic generated classes are partial I added a manually edited .cs file with all documentation inside. This works quite well for classes declaration, but what about their properties and methods?

Anyone knows a better strategy to document strongly typed datasets?